# Regarding mysql limits

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx

I read something about updating globals such as net_read_timeout, connect_timeout etc to avoid lost connection on MySQL databases. So my question is simply this

If I execute these queries, do I have to restart mysql service on Ubuntu & Nginx?

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout=600
```

My question is really because when I use this query, it seems like they updated, but are they operating even though I don't restart mysql service etc?

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will definitely work. Only 'certain' OS's need rebooting after minor changes (I'm staying neutral). But don't take my word for it, see:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html

It says:

> Most of them can be changed dynamically at runtime using the SET
>   statement, which enables you to modify operation of the server without
>   having to stop and restart it.

Then look in the table further down and you can see that `connect_timeout` and `net_read_timeout` are both dynamic.

I guess that the documentation has a purpose after all?